# Python: How to fix interpolation routine

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a piece of code to apply a filter to a data set. The filter has two key bits of data, wavelength and throughput. The data file also has two key bits of data, wavelength and flux. Unfortunately, the wavelengths in the filter file and the data file do not always match up. The code below is intended to use `y=mx+c` to interpolate between the data points and so obtain an approximate value for the flux through the filter at wavelengths that are not equal to the wavelengths in the filter file.

```
def openfilterfile(filterfile):
    throughput=[]
    filterwavelength=[]
    text_file2 = open(filterfile, "r")
    lines2 = text_file2.read()
    #print lines2
    text_file2.close()
    b = [float(y) for y in lines2.split()]
    b1=0
    b2=1
    while b1<len(b):
        filterwavelength.append(b[b1])
        throughput.append(b[b2])
        b1+=2
        b2+=2
    print len(filterwavelength), len(throughput)
    f=scipy.interpolate.interp1d(filterwavelength, throughput, kind='linear')
    xnew = filterwavelength
    ynew = f(xnew)
    pylab.plot(filterwavelength, throughput, xnew, ynew)
    pylab.xlim(0, 25000)
    pylab.show()
    return filterwavelength, throughput

def accountforfilter(wavelength, flux, filterwavelength, throughput):

    filteredwavelength=[]
    filteredflux=[]

    for i in range(len(wavelength)):
        for j in range(len(wavelength)):
            if wavelength[i]==filterwavelength[j]:
                j=filterwavelength.index(wavelength[i])
                filteredwavelength.append(wavelength[i])
                filteredflux.append(flux[i]*throughput[j])
            elif wavelength[i]<filterwavelength[j]<wavelength[i+1]:
                filteredwavelength.append(wavelength[i])
                filteredflux.append(flux[i]*f(wavelength[i]))
            elif wavelength[i]<filterwavelength[j]:
                i+=1
            elif wavelength[i]>filterwavelength[j+1]:
                j+=1

return filteredwavelength, filteredflux
```

When I run this, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\05.12.2014.py", line 103, in <module>
    filteredwavelength, filteredflux = accountforfilter(wavelength, flux, filterwavelength, throughput)
  File "C:\Python27\05.12.2014.py", line 87, in accountforfilter
    if wavelength[i]==filterwavelength[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I change it so that `j` is over the `range(filterwavelength)`, then the program runs continuously, but I think it is looping over all j for each i, which takes forever. Is there a better way of writing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, That's why you're getting the exception--
`j` is using the wrong max length. You definitely need to change:

`for j in range(len(wavelength)):`

to

`for j in range(len(filterwavelength)):`

People have no idea what you mean by "looping when I don't want it to be"

Answer (score 1):

You have `j` range over `wavelength`, but then use it as an index into `filteredwavelength` (which is initially empty).  You also modify `i` and `j` within the loops, which are usually (but not always) suspect.